# How to insert a number between columns in latex table?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

Can you please help me with the code to insert a number between columns in latex table? In the table below I want to have numbers for "Difference" between column 1-2, 2-3, 3-4, 4-5, in total 4 different values (0.736    0.298   0.144   0.461).

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{8.5in} \setlength{\pdfpageheight}{11in}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t!] 
\caption{Moderating effect} 
\bigskip
\centering

\begin{tabular}{lccccc} \hline \hline 
Numbers& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
Mean &2.658 &1.923& 1.625&  1.480&  1.020\\
Difference &&&&&\\

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you expect that table will calculate difference itself?

Comment: No, I have the numbers, 0.736 0.298 0.144 0.461

Comment: ok, this is simple. just insert new columns for difference in table. Please extend your code fragment to complete small document.

Comment: Do you mean to add 3 columns and use \multicolumn {2}{c}{..} command?

Comment: A plot of some sort might be a more effective way of showing this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably something like the following?

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\widthof{0.000}}}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t!] 
\caption{Moderating effect} 
\bigskip
\centering

\begin{tabular}{l*{10}{p{\widthof{00}}}} \hline \hline 
Numbers    & \mc{1} & \mc{2} & \mc{3} & \mc{4} & \mc{5}\\
Mean       & \mc{2.658} & \mc{1.923}& \mc{1.625}&  \mc{1.480}&  \mc{1.020}\\
Difference & & \mc{0.736} & \mc{0.298} & \mc{0.144} &\mc{0.461}\\

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively and as suggested by [Sveinung](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531647/how-to-insert-a-number-between-columns-in-latex-table/531652#comment1344310_531652) one can also use the following definition of `\mc`:

```
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{wc{\widthof{0.000}}}{#1}}
```

Comment: Since you are loading `array` and cells are one line only, why not use `w`-columns instead of `p`-columns, i.e. `\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{wc{\widthof{0.000}}}{#1}}`

Comment: @Sveinung: Thanks for reminding me of the `w` column type. Although I really like the idea of this recently introduced column type I somehow keep forgetting to use it.

Answer (score 7):

Add more columns. I also introduced a small amount of negative space.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lc*{8}{@{\hspace{-4pt}}c}}
\toprule
Numbers    &   1   &&   2   &&   3   &&   4   &&   5   \\
\midrule
Mean       & 2.658 && 1.923 && 1.625 && 1.480 && 1.020 \\
Difference &&     0.736 && 0.298 && 0.144 && 0.461 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It is not very clear what you like to obtain, It can be understand as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Moderating effect}
\label{tab:diferences}
\centering
\footnotesize
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{l*{9}{S[table-format=1.3]} } 
    \toprule
Numbers & 1     &{diff} & 2     &{diff} & 3     &{diff} & 4     &{diff} & 5         \\
Mean    & 2.658 & 0.736 & 1.923 & 0.298 & 1.625 & 0.144 & 1.480 & 0.461 & 1.020     \\   
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
\item   fdfdfd
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Moderating effect}
\label{tab:diferences}
\centering
\footnotesize
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{l*{9}{S[table-format=1.3]} }
    \toprule
Numbers     & 1     &{diff} & 2     & {diff} & 3     &{diff} & 4     & {diff} & 5       \\
Mean        & 2.658 &       & 1.923 &        & 1.625 &       & 1.480 &        & 1.020   \\
    \midrule
Differences &       & 0.736 &       & 0.298  &       & 0.144 &       & 0.461  &         \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
\item   fdfdfd
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If these are not a case, please provide a sketch, which show what you like to have.

Answer (score 3):

The following is for all people who use ConTeXt and try to achieve the same table layout.

With the `natural table` environment you can create merged table cells with the `nc` (number of columns) or `nx` keys in the optional argument at the begin of the cell.

The width of the cell can be set before the start of the table environment but since we do this inside of a float environment the settings will be local to the current float.

```
\setuppapersize[letter]

\setupcaption
  [table]
  [location=top]

\starttext

\startplacetable[title={Moderating effect}]
    \setupTABLE [start]          [width=1.5em,align=middle,frame=off]
    \setupTABLE [column] [first] [width=fit,align=flushleft]
    \setupTABLE [row]    [first] [topframe=on,bottomframe=on]
    \setupTABLE [row]    [last]  [bottomframe=on]
    \bTABLE
        \bTR
            \bTD Numbers \eTD
            \bTD[nc=2] 1 \eTD
            \bTD[nc=2] 2 \eTD
            \bTD[nc=2] 3 \eTD
            \bTD[nc=2] 4 \eTD
            \bTD[nc=2] 5 \eTD
        \eTR
        \bTR
            \bTD Mean        \eTD
            \bTD[nc=2] 2.658 \eTD
            \bTD[nc=2] 1.923 \eTD
            \bTD[nc=2] 1.625 \eTD
            \bTD[nc=2] 1.480 \eTD
            \bTD[nc=2] 1.020 \eTD
        \eTR
        \bTR
            \bTD Difference  \eTD
            \bTD             \eTD
            \bTD[nc=2] 0.736 \eTD
            \bTD[nc=2] 0.298 \eTD
            \bTD[nc=2] 0.144 \eTD
            \bTD[nc=2] 0.461 \eTD
            \bTD             \eTD
        \eTR
    \eTABLE
\stopplacetable

\stoptext
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Example 1 – nested tabular**

The simplest way to insert the four numbers between the columns, is to span the last five cells in the third row in a multicolumn. Then, you include a new tabular with four centred columns in the spanned cells. You may either use 5+4 `D`-columns (from the package [dcolumn](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/dcolumns)), or use 5+4 ordinary `c`-columns. This works very well as long as all cells are opproximatly of the same width:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{array, dcolumn, booktabs, caption}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.05}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[bh!] 
\caption{Moderating effect -- \emph{using c-columns and nested tabular}} 
\centering

\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{5}{c}@{}} \toprule

Numbers    & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     \\
Mean       & 2.658 & 1.923 & 1.625 & 1.480 & 1.020 \\
Difference & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\begin{tabular}{@{}*{4}{c}@{}}
                                 0.736 & 0.298 & 0.144 & 0.461
                                 \end{tabular}%
                                }\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[bh!] 
\centering
\caption{Moderating effect -- \emph{using D-columns and nested tabular}} 

\begin{tabular}{@{}l!{\quad}*{5}{D{.}{.}{1,3}}} \toprule

Numbers    & \mc{1} & \mc{2} & \mc{3} & \mc{4}  & \mc{5}   \\
Mean       & 2.658  & 1.923  & 1.625  & 1.480   & 1.020    \\
Difference & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\begin{tabular}{*{4}{D{.}{.}{1,3}}}
                                 0.736 & 0.298 & 0.144 & 0.461
                                \end{tabular}%
                               }\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Example 2 – Extra columns and D-columns**

And here is a variant of @egreg's tabular using `D`-columns from the [dcolumn](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/dcolumns) package. The benefit is that if you have rows where the numbers have less than three decimal, or if you use figures with proportional width in the tabular, the numbers will still be centred around the decimal point. I have added two rows to demonstrate the effect.

In addition, I have added more space in the table, and used the mandatory [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package to draw the rules.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, dcolumn, booktabs}
\newcommand{\mci}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.05}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[tbh!] 
\caption{Moderating effect} 
\bigskip
\centering

\begin{tabular}{@{}l!{\quad}*{9}{@{\hspace{-1pt}}D{.}{.}{1,3}}} \toprule

Numbers    & \mci{1}  && \mci{2} && \mci{3}  && \mci{4}  && \mci{5} \\
Mean       & 2.658    && 1.923   && 1.625    && 1.480    && 1.020   \\
Difference &&       0.736 &&   0.298 &&    0.144 &&    0.461 &      \\
\midrule
Mean       & 7.68     && 4.94    && 1.62     && 1.48     && 1.02    \\
Difference &&       0.75  &&    1.99  &&    0.94  &&   0.46  &      \\

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```